# $L^2$-closure of polynomials in a complex variable on an open bounded set

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

The density of the polynomials $p(z,\bar z)$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, where $z\in\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ and $\Omega$ is an open bounded set, is the consequence of more or less standard facts in complex and functional analysis.

Now I was wondering what space one obtains if instead one takes the $L^2$-closure of the polynomials $p(z)$ in the $z$-variable only. Is it a somewhat `classical' space? I could not figure out what that space is.

Comment: I'm not sure if they're exactly what you're looking for, but look up Bergman spaces.

Comment: @Jose27 +1. In particular, the subspace of analytic functions IS closed in $L^2$

Comment: That is true, you're correct, now I see it. The subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$-functions that are also holomorphic is indeed a closed subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$, when $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ is open and bounded. So now the suspicion is natural: does the $L^2$-closure of polynomials in $z$ coincide with the closed subspace of holomorphic $L^2$-functions? Or is the former just a proper closed subspace of the latter?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: using Mean Value Property of analytic functions it is easy to see that boundedness in $L^{2}$ implies local boundedness for analytic functions. Hence if a sequence of polynomials (in $z$) converges in $L^{2}$ then it is a normal family and the limit is also analytic. [This is not a complete description of the closure of polynomials].

Comment: Thanks Kavi Rama Murthy for editing your answer. Yes, the $L^2$-closure of polynomials in $z$ over $\Omega$ naturally (and strictly) contains the holomorphic functions on $\Omega$. My original question is precisely whether one can characterize the former space explicitly.

Comment: @TullioRicci87 To my knowledge a complete description of this space is not available even when $\Omega$ is the open unit disk.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murty: as I commented after Jose27's remark, the subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$-functions that are also holomorphic is indeed a closed subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$, when $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ is open and bounded. The question is whether the $L^2$-closure of polynomials in $z$ coincides with the closed subspace of holomorphic $L^2$-functions, or instead the former space is just a proper closed subspace of the latter.